# How can I browse output of any random command in quickfix window?

Tags: vim

I'd like to run some `$RANDOM_COMMAND`, and have the results opened in ("piped to") the quickfix window (`:copen`/`:cfile`). Is this possible, without having to define some commands in vimrc? (Hopefully in some "simple way", i.e. I'd like to be able to memorize this so I can run this on any new random box with vanilla vim that I'll have to login to.)

**edit:** initially didn't know how to express "simple way" more precisely, but now I know at least partially: I'd much prefer **an answer of 1, max 2 lines**.

**edit2:** tried something like below <sup>(from [this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-do-edit-the-quickfix-window-td1163140.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6412831/98528))</sup>:

```
:call setqflist(split(system('RANDOM_COMMAND'), '\n'))
:copen
```

but didn't seem to work anyway :/ (and *mucho* ugly too)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmh, found the simplest solution in the end, by reading through the [regular vimdoc for quickfix window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix):

```
:cex system('$RANDOM_COMMAND') | copen
```

(the `| copen` part is optional).

*Still, [Ingo Karkat's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083390/98528) can have usability advantage, as on consecutive runs it's enough to run shorter :grep there.*

Comment: Is it possible to populate the quickfix window with data from vim EX mode commads like :ls? Quickfix window with list of all open buffers?
I tried `cexp ":execute ls"` but it doesnt work. Need some help with vimscripting

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this:

```
:set makeprg=$RANDOM_COMMAND
:make
:copen
```

Or, execute the command and capture the output in a temporary file:

```
:! $RANDOM_COMMAND > out
:cfile out
:copen
```

In any way, the output must match with the `'errorformat'` setting, so that Vim can parse the file name and line numbers (if you need those; but otherwise, you could just use a scratch buffer as well the quickfix list).

### [edit] Some improvements

To make this a **oneliner**, then somewhat shortened, you can:

```
:set mp=RANDOM_COMMAND | make | copen
```

**Whitespaces** in command must be **escaped with backslash**; also, the `make` command can take arguments, which get expanded in place of a `$*`; a more full-blown example thus:

```
:set mp=mycommand\ -d\ $PWD\ $* | make myarg | copen
```

Alternatively, similar thing can be done with `:set grepprg` and `:grep`, giving even shorter line:

```
:set gp=mycommand\ -d\ $PWD\ $* | gr myarg | copen
```

Comment: Hm, I kinda found both of those, but they were both too long for me, only I didn't know how to express this; now seeing your answer I think I know: I'd prefer an answer of 1, max 2 lines... and most ideally something like `:! $RANDOM_COMMAND | :copen`...

Comment: hm, is it possible to type all your commands in one line, some kinda `:set makeprg=$FOOBAR ; :make ; :copen` or something?

Comment: Sure: `set makeprg=$FOOBAR|exe 'make'|copen`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked. I'll let myself edit your answer to add some more details I needed too. Also, I understand I can escape spaces only with a backslash?

Comment: Hm, given some [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6549828/98528), I think the `| exe 'make'| ` should work also when shortened to just `| make |`? or not?